# How to retrive first row, first column cell value of a command process output using linux command

Tags: linux, command

I want to get the value **385** which is in the process output of below code, I want to do this through command itself, is there any way to do this.

I don't have enough knowledge in Linux commands, please help me to achieve this.

```
#ps -u root|grep java|awk '{print $1}'
```

385

2018

2048

4242

21290

25110

25589

26166

Answer (score 3):

You could put the output in a shell variable like

```
var=$(ps -u root|grep java|awk '{print $1}'|head -1)
```

and you may be happy to learn more about [pgrep](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pgrep.htm).

As [GoT answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15969194/841108), the `head -1` command gives you the first line, and you put it into `$var`

I suggest to read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `head -1`

```
#ps -u root | grep java | head -1
```